# Android - Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to go to another activity but the app crashes with these errors.
I have 2 activity:

1. Acivity Chat
2. FriendProfileViewActivity

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.newchatapp/com.mycompany.newchatapp.Activities.FriendProfileViewActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class 
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class 
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class 
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

**Here is the XML Code of ChatActivity.**

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
    android:padding="5dp">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewProfile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/friendpic"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="-5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_user" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/friendname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/friendpic"
                android:fontFamily="@font/alegreya_sc_italic"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/friendname"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/friendpic"
                android:text="offline"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**JAVA CODE for Chat**

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.viewProfile);
relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, FriendProfileViewActivity.class);
    intent1.putExtra("friendId", friendId);
    startActivity(intent1);
    });
```

**XML code for FriendProfileViewActivity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".Activities.FriendProfileViewActivity">
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/friendProfilePic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/friendProfileName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/friendProfilePic"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Friend Name"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/friendProfileName"
    android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/friendProfileName"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="About Me: "
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/friendAboutMe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/friendProfileName"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/about"
    android:text="@string/status"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/friendAboutMe"
    android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/friendAboutMe"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Phone Number: "
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/friendPhoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/friendAboutMe"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/phoneNumber"
    android:text="@string/fakeNumber"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/friendPhoneNumber"
    android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/blockUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="Block User"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

**JAVA CODE FriendProfileViewActivity**

```
public class FriendProfileViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView name, about, phoneNumber;
    Button blockUser;
    CircleImageView profilepic;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String friendId, friendPhoneNumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friend_profile_view);

        profilepic = findViewById(R.id.friendProfilePic);
        name = findViewById(R.id.friendProfileName);
        about = findViewById(R.id.friendAboutMe);
        phoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.friendPhoneNumber);
        blockUser = findViewById(R.id.blockUser);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        friendId = intent.getStringExtra("friendId");

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(friendId);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    Users users = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                    name.setText(users.getUsername());
                    about.setText(users.getAboutMe());
                    phoneNumber.setText(users.getFullPhoneNumber());
                   // Glide.with(FriendProfileViewActivity.this).load(users.getProfilephotoURL())
                       //     .fitCenter().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user).into(profilepic);
                    friendPhoneNumber = users.getFullPhoneNumber();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        blockUser.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Block User");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_block);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setMessage("Do you wan to block User?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {

                BlockList blockList = new BlockList(friendPhoneNumber);
                DatabaseReference blockUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
                        getReference("BlockList").child(user.getUid());
                blockUser.child(friendId).setValue(blockList);

                BlockList blockList1 = new BlockList(user.getPhoneNumber());
                blockUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
                        getReference("BlockList").child(friendId);
                blockUser.child(user.getUid()).setValue(blockList1);

                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ChatsList")
                        .child(user.getUid());
                databaseReference.child(friendId).removeValue();
                DatabaseReference friendChatList = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ChatsList")
                        .child(friendId);
                friendChatList.child(user.getUid()).removeValue();
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(FriendProfileViewActivity.this, MainScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent1);

            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there more to the error? Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: @Zee There was one more on the stack trace. I have added it. Please Check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I quickly ran your code and got THIS stack trace:

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:656)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:738)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:832)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at za.co.Test.testit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6910)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2757)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2875)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1578)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6623)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ScaleType FIT_CENTER not supported.
        at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.setScaleType(CircleImageView.java:134)
```

Removing scale type from friendProfilePic fixed the error.

To add to this, they do make a note of this in the documentation of the library: The ScaleType is always CENTER_CROP and you'll get an exception if you try to change it. This is (currently) by design as it's perfectly fine for profile images.

Please make sure to read your stacktraces carefully (if this was the issue) it will save you tons of grief :)